pl/sql packages function doesn't return correct value
I'm learning pl/sql, I'm getting started on packages, so basically I'm trying to find how many istances of a char is there in a string, i'm using live SQL of Oracle to execute queries etc... but a function that perfectly works outside of the block when written in the package body won't work
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE string_manipulator IS
    FUNCTION char_occurrences(input_char IN VARCHAR2, input_string VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER;
END string_manipulator;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY string_manipulator IS

    FUNCTION char_occurrences(input_char IN VARCHAR2, input_string IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
        char_found_var NUMBER;
        BEGIN
            SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(UPPER(input_string), UPPER(input_char))
            INTO char_found_var
            FROM dual;
        RETURN char_found_var;
    END char_occurrences;
END string_manipulator;

DECLARE 
    input_string VARCHAR2(50) := 'test';
    char_to_find VARCHAR2(50):= 'e';
    char_found_var NUMBER;
BEGIN
    char_found_var := string_manipulator.char_occurrences(input_string, char_to_find);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(char_found_var || ' char found ');
END;

this always returns 0.
But when i do something like
DECLARE 
    input_string VARCHAR2(50) := 'test';
    char_to_find VARCHAR2(50):= 'e';
    char_found_var NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(UPPER(input_string), UPPER(char_to_find))
    INTO char_found_var
    FROM dual;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(char_found_var || ' char found ');
END;


it perfectly works
Any solution to this?

Just to comment on the code, you don't need to select from dual. You can just assign the expression directly to the variable when you declare it: char_found_var number := regexp_count(upper(input_string), upper(input_char)); Also, you don't need to put everything in uppercase. A lot of people are attached to it, but in my view it's just a bad habit, as it would be in any other programming language.

@WilliamRobertson thanks for the comments, appreciate them a lot, I use uppercase mainly to have clear what i'm trying to do but i understand your point, also thanks for the tip about the assignment of the valu

That's because you wrongly used parameters when calling packaged function.
Commented line is yours; uncommented is mine, and it works:
SQL>     DECLARE
  2         input_string    VARCHAR2 (50) := 'test';
  3         char_to_find    VARCHAR2 (50) := 'e';
  4         char_found_var  NUMBER;
  5      BEGIN
  6         -- char_found_var := string_manipulator.char_occurrences (input_string, char_to_find);
  7            char_found_var := string_manipulator.char_occurrences (char_to_find, input_string);
  8         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (char_found_var || ' char found ');
  9      END;
 10  /
1 char found

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>


PL/SQL allows 2 ways of passing arguments to a function or procedure: positional notation and named notation. Your code uses positional notation which (as you noticed... you got the order wrong) is more error prone. With named notation, the order doesn't matter, there is less chance of errors and the code is more readable:
DECLARE 
    input_string VARCHAR2(50) := 'test';
    char_to_find VARCHAR2(50):= 'e';
    char_found_var NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_char_found_var := string_manipulator.char_occurrences
                          (input_char => v_char_to_find,  
                           input_string => v_input_string );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_char_found_var || ' char found ');
END;
/

Here is the reference to the docs.
